IOS camera does not work in pwa but works in browser
I have problems when using the camera (getUserMedia) on the iphone. When using it in the browser (safari) it works perfectly but as soon as I add the pwa to the homescreen it stops working.
My code setup:
<head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" width="200" height="200" autoplay playsinline muted crossorigin></video>
    <script>
        const video = document.getElementById('video');

        const events = [
          'play', 'waiting', 'loadstart', 'progress', 'suspend',
          'durationchange', 'loadedmetadata', 'loadeddata', 
          'canplay', 'playing', 'canplaythrough', 'timeupdate'
        ];

        events.forEach(e => {
          video.addEventListener(e, () => {
            console.log(`${e} event fired`);
          });
        });

        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(function(stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                        video.play();
                    };
                
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!", error);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

my manifest.json:
{ "name": "Test-App", "display": "standalone",...
If I remove "display:": "standalone" (or fullscreen, does not matter), the video stream works again...
I've tried to see what events are being fired by the video element and if the pwa is open only the loadstart, progress and suspend (in that order) events are fired. If it is opend in the browser every expected event is fired. There are no errors, nothing...

For me it's not working on iOS 14 (Specific version: 15.7.1) only,

Depending on what version of iOS you're testing on, your problem may be related to this bug in WebKit: In PWA, HTML Video Element may be unable to play stream from 'getUserMedia()'
Though I haven't tested it myself, this bug claims to be resolved in iOS 17+
However, others are reporting similar unresolved issues on iOS 17.4.1: Camera freezes on installed PWA, as of iOS 17.4.1

I use 17.4.1 but the worst part is I’ve   accessed the same pwa on a different device on 17.4.1 but it works??? Exact same safari settings.. I’ve checked everything still different outcome
